# How to detect if part of a `UIBezierPath` lies in a given `CGRect`?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgrect

I'm currently trying to figure out how to detect if a given `UIBezierPath` intersects a given `CGRect` at any point.
So for example I would have the following:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
  arcCenter: CGPoint.zero,
  radius: 100,
  startAngle: 0,
  endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
  clockwise: false
)

let rectangle = CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 30, height: 30)
```

And now I would like to figure out if `circlePath` at any point lies within `rectangle`.

How would I go about this?

#### Update:

Is there some way to access an underlying mathematical function of the path? This could allow me to calculate if an intersection with a given 'CGRect' occurs or not.

Comment: Create custom view, override `drawRect`, draw your path in it, your new  view has frame which is `CGRect`, use `CGRectIntersectsRect` function to determine intersection of two rects...

Comment: Well that's basically what I'm currently doing. But that's not sufficient. Say I draw `circlePath` in the center of a custom view: The point `(100, 100)` would register as intersecting, despite the path not even being at that point.

Comment: Yeah, but you should draw path that will border your view sides. http://www.kevinhouston.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/circle-in-square.png Of course view background color is clearColor I guess you want, and borders are invisible too...

Comment: Anyway it is not that good, because there are blind zones (corners) and it detects rects intersection while path is not...

Comment: Take a look at `CGContextPathContainsPoint` function, maybe it will help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextPathContainsPoint. You can get points from your `CGRect` and check them for containing in your path.

Comment: I am drawing a path that borders the view sides, but as you've said: there are corners.

Comment: The same exists for 'UIBezierPath': 'contains(point:)'. But then I would have to check a limited amount of points along the path.